# Netbeans project won't run

Tags: java, netbeans

I enrolled myself in the University of Helsinki's Java course. To follow along with this course, I had to install the NetBeans IDE and complete their exercise through this IDE.

However, when running a simple Hello World program:

[image: Hello World]

I receive this error:

[image: Error Message]

Does anyone know how to fix this error? If it helps, I was asked to download this as well:

[image: Temurin]

And I installed NetBeans from this link: https://download.mooc.fi/tmcbeans/installers/tmcbeans_1.4.0_installer.dmg which was provided to me by the website.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this: Right click on the Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Change the Source/Binary Format from JDK 6 to newer version.

Comment: @sittsering yes that worked great. could you post this comment as an answer so i can accept it? thank you very much.

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: 
Right click on the Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Change the Source/Binary Format from JDK 6 to newer version.